# How to create a python module?

Tags: python

My current directory structure looks like the following:

```
 MainProject-- src---python---python_client/my_module/__init__.py
                                                L___/foo.py
                                                L_/utils.py
                                        |
                                        L_/tests/__init__.py
                                               L_ test_foo.py
```

Now in test_foo.py, I want to `import my_module`
Now I can make changes inside python_client dir but not on directories above that..

THe issue I am facing is `import my_module` is not recognized/valid.. What should I add/ modify in order to make imports like that?
Thanks

Edit:
  I have a question.. Why does something like this works https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py
They are importing functions from different files... 
But if in foo.py , I do

```
import my_module.utils I get an error?
```

Comment: Don't use periods in package directory names.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Sorry.. that was a typo. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/MainProject/src/python/python_client
```

You should then be able to import `my_module` with:

```
import my_module
```

There seems to be a confusion about a module and a package. `my_module` above is actually a package. `foo` and `utils` are modules inside the package `my_module`.

It is always a good idea to set the `PYTHONPATH` to the root of your project and check to make sure you are able to import your packages or modules by running the python interpreter.

More on the Python [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).